# Rails Regex Date Validation

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-3

Sorry I'm at wits end here guys.

I've got this

```
  validates :departing_at, :format => {
    # 2012-07-14 10:00 am
    :with => /^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}) ([ap]m)$/,
    :message => "must be date and time"
  }
```

But it just won't validate 2012-07-14 10:00 am or any other date format that matches that regex.

But if I place this inside of the controller

```
pattern = /^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}) ([ap]m)$/

if params[:vacation][:departing_at] =~ pattern
  raise "works"
else
  raise params[:vacation][:departing_at].to_yaml
  raise "doesn't work"
end
```

it prints out "works" any ideas guys? :(

Comment: Not a real answer to your question... but I'm sure there's a much better way of validating Date and Time than with a regex.

Comment: Ah I'm just using that along side client_side_validations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this overkill regex:

```
:with => /^(\d{4})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{2})\s(\d{2})\:(\d{2})\s([aApP][mM])$/,
```